# stackexchange-like submit comment window

Tags: comments, forms

I am developing my comments submission form and i would like to create sth like http://wordpress.stackexchange.com window ( the one i am writting now in) with B, I, add hyper-link and photo, and bullets.
Are you using your own code?
Is there any plugin or someone could link me any web how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wordpress's built in TinyMCE editor anywhere in PHP code using [`wp_editor()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor). This would output all the necessary styles and scripts for it to load, and there are a lot of options documented in the codex link above.

Answer (score 0):

Here [stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), there are plugins for it just go to the wordpress plugin site and search for `Markdown editor`